# Do same function on a list of dataframes and save them in new dataframes with new names

Tags: r

I have data frames A, B, C and want to modify each data frame in the same way according to dataframe D. It is like:

```
A = data.frame(x=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),type=c('1','2','3','2','1','3'))
B = data.frame(x=c('g','h','i') ,type=c('1','2','3'))
C = data.frame(x=c('j','k','l','m'),type=c('2','3','1','2') )
D = data.frame(type=c('1','2','3','4'),newtype=c('I','II','III','IV') )
```

Firstly, i want to change the types in A,B,C to new type in D.
To A, i can do:

```
A$type <- D$newtype[match(A$type, D$type)]
```

Now how to do the same function on B and C? I have viewed other questions and thought it should be realized using lapply but i can't write it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would store `A`, `B`, `C` in a `list` and then merge `data.frame` entries with `D` by `type`.

**Using `purrr::map` and `dplyr::left_join`**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(list(A, B, C), ~left_join(.x, D))
#[[1]]
#  x type newtype
#1 a    1       I
#2 b    2      II
#3 c    3     III
#4 d    2      II
#5 e    1       I
#6 f    3     III
#
#[[2]]
#  x type newtype
#1 g    1       I
#2 h    2      II
#3 i    3     III
#
#[[3]]
#  x type newtype
#1 j    2      II
#2 k    3     III
#3 l    1       I
#4 m    2      II
```

**In base R using `Map` and `merge`**

```
Map(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "type"), list(A, B, C), list(D))
#[[1]]
#  type x newtype
#1    1 a       I
#2    1 e       I
#3    2 b      II
#4    2 d      II
#5    3 c     III
#6    3 f     III
#
#[[2]]
#  type x newtype
#1    1 g       I
#2    2 h      II
#3    3 i     III
#
#[[3]]
#  type x newtype
#1    1 l       I
#2    2 j      II
#3    2 m      II
#4    3 k     III
```

Comment: Thank you! It is very useful. And here it is another question, if the type of some values in the A, B, C can't be matched with the new type in D (as 4, 5, 6...), it should be changed to "other". What function can help me to realize it?

Comment: @FanWu Well, you need at least one column variable with matching entries for a merge/join (it doesn't have to have the same name, see `?merge` for details). That's the premise for any form of (left/right/inner/outer) joining operation. If you have two `data.frame`s with pairwise-matching rows you can do a simple `cbind` of columns. But that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

"Literally" I think it would be something like:

```
A = data.frame(x=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),type=c('1','2','3','2','1','3'))
B = data.frame(x=c('g','h','i') ,type=c('1','2','3'))
C = data.frame(x=c('j','k','l','m'),type=c('2','3','1','2') )
D = data.frame(type=c('1','2','3','4'),newtype=c('I','II','III','IV') )

list2env(
  lapply(list(A = A, B = B, C = C), function(x) {
    x$type <- D$newtype[match(x$type, D$type)]
    x
  }),
  envir = parent.frame())

# A
# x type
#1 a    I
#2 b   II
#3 c  III
#4 d   II
#5 e    I
#6 f  III
```

Comment: Brilliant:) But you can shorten it using `within`: `list2env(
  lapply(list(A = A, B = B, C = C), function(x) within(x, type <- D$newtype[match(type, D$type)])
  ),
  envir = parent.frame())`